# ASP.NET can't include MySql namespace in asp-tags NOT CodeBehind

Tags: asp.net, mysql, dll, namespaces, include

Trying to include MySql namespace:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MySql.Data" %>
```

But getting an error... Have checked, in `References` tab there is included required dll.
Also , I've included in CodeBehind namespace for MySQL ( and no error for the CodeBehind ).

But if I try to include the including code in aspx code body, not CodeBehind, I'm catching an error, that it can't see such a namespace when I'm navigating to the page via browser.

How to fix such an issue?